# Javascript function error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'target' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Javascript error coming don't know how to solve this on live server its working fine . now i am upgrading version of CodeIgniter so its not working on my code . but good working on 1.72

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" >
     function doPostBack(col_id,ord_id,off_set) 
     {
            var theform;
            if (window.navigator.appName.toLowerCase().indexOf("microsoft") > -1) {
                theform = document.searchForm;
            }
            else {
                theform = document.forms["searchForm"];
            }
            theform.href="href='http://www.google.com';"
            theform.target='_self';
            if(col_id!=null || col_id!=""){
            theform.COL_ID.value = col_id;
            }
            if(ord_id!=null || ord_id!=""){
            theform.ORD_ID.value = ord_id;
            }
            if(off_set!=null || off_set!=""){
            theform.OFF_SET.value = off_set;
            }
            theform.submit();
      }
      </script>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please elaborate little by giving an example

Comment: Show some code that you have written in any of the files and tell us what you want to accomplish.

Comment: <li><a title="<?php echo $_SESSION['currency_code']; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo sprintf("%01.2f", currency_convert($total_price, $_SESSION['currency_code'])); ?>" href="<?= site_url('product/shopcart') ?>"> <?php echo $_SESSION['currency_code']; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo sprintf("%01.2f", currency_convert($total_price, $_SESSION['currency_code'])); ?></a></li>

Comment: focus on currency_convert function

Comment: in global_variable.php

Comment: this function is . and global_variable.php file is in the route of codeigniter . now how i can use this function

Comment: move it to `helper` folder under application and autoload the function in `autoload.php`

Comment: i tried this one but it corrupt all other route files

Comment: $this->cart->total_items

Comment: if i place file in helper and use autoload to load helper class then cart error arise . even i autoload the cart library

Comment: Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: CI_Loader::$cart

Filename: helpers/logos_banner_menus_helper.php

Line Number: 22

Comment: I can help you only if you post your code here.

Comment: re edit your question with proper code try not to posy lots of code in comments.

Comment: if($this->cart->total_items()>0)
{
 $cart_items=array_sort($this->cart->contents(),'name',SORT_ASC);
 $product_ids_count=array();
 $product_ids_quantity=array();
 $product_ids_count_grater=array();
 $m_all_product_quantity=array();
 foreach($cart_items as $split_items)
 {
  $product_ids_count[]=$split_items['id'];
  
  
}

Comment: cart library is not working in helper

Comment: In helper `$this` will not work unless you have initialized the CodeIgniter instance to a variable. first add `$CI =& get_instance();` then use `$CI` in place of `$this`

Comment: Did your problem got solved??

Comment: yes i places that helper in view, with controller

Answer (score 0):

best solution for this is create the helpers
and rest add code in MY_Controller. those methods you want to run automatic in controller so that you can call those methods in view